# Tkintermapview do not display the map

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkintermapview

I create an ip location tracker with a GUI. The app supposed to show details of an specific ip from an API. Everything works right, but when I want to display a map for that specific location, the canvas for map appear but the map is not appear.

To display map I used tkintermapview from tkinter. To display the map I used latitude and longitude from that API to parse them to my map.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkintermapview
import requests
import ipaddress

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def ipFinder(outputMsg, inputValue):
    try:
        ipAddress = inputValue.get()
        ipaddress.ip_address(ipAddress)
        response = requests.get(f'https://ipapi.co/{ipAddress}/json/').json()
        ip_version = response.get("version")
        city = response.get("city")
        region = response.get("region")
        country = response.get("country_name")
        postalcode = response.get("postal")
        continent = response.get("continent_code")
        lat = response.get("latitude")
        lng = response.get("longitude")
        outputMsg.config(text= "Information for " + inputValue.get() + " are:" + "\n"
                            "IP Version" + ' : ' + str(ip_version) + "\n"
                            "CITY" + ' : ' + str(city) + "\n"
                            "REGION" + ' : ' + str(region) + "\n"
                            "Country" + ' : ' + str(country) + "\n"
                            "Postal Code" + ' : ' + str(postalcode) + "\n"
                            "Continent" + ' : ' + str(continent) + "\n" 
                            "Latitude" + ' : ' + str(lat) + "\n" 
                            "Longitude" + ' : ' + str(lng) + "\n")   
    except:
        outputMsg.config(text="Please Enter Correct IP")
    
    # Define LabelFrame to show the map on my app
    my_label = tk.LabelFrame(Tk)
    my_label.grid(pady=20)

    # tkintermapview to fullfield my label with exact location of phone using lat and lng
    map_widget = tkintermapview.TkinterMapView(my_label, width=300, height=300, corner_radius=0)
    map_widget.set_position(lat, lng)
    # set_marker to set the marker on my map to see the location
    map_widget.set_marker(lat, lng, text = "Ip Location")
    # set_zoom to set the zoom on my map to actually see something
    map_widget.set_zoom(10)
    map_widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    map_widget.grid()


Tk = tk.Tk()

Tk.geometry("600x600+{}+{}".format(600, 600))

authorLable = tk.Label(Tk, text="Robert", background='#28334A', foreground="#FFFFFF")
authorLable.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

inputString = tk.StringVar()

websiteName = tk.Label(Tk, text="Enter ip", background='#28334A', foreground="#F65058")
input_entry = tk.Entry(Tk, textvariable=inputString)
websiteName.grid(row=1)
input_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

outputMsg = tk.Label(Tk, background='#28334A', foreground="#F65058")
outputMsg.grid(row=3, columnspan=4)


button = tk.Button(Tk, text="Check IP", command=lambda : ipFinder(outputMsg, inputString))
button.grid(row=2, columnspan=4)

Tk.title('IP Checker')
Tk.configure(background='#28334A')
Tk.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
Tk.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
Tk.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
Tk.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
contents = tk.Frame(Tk)
contents.grid(row=1, column=1)
Tk.mainloop()
```

Here is an ss with the app:

[image]

Any help will be welcome. Thanks in advenced.

Comment: TkinterMapView  is not "from tkinter". It's a third-party module the supposedly works with tkinter. I suggest you contact its author(s) with questions on how to use it.

Comment: It's from tkintermapview which is from tkinter

Comment: If it was truly "from" tkinter then wouldn't you expect that to reflect in your `import` statement?  Would it not read `from tkinter import  tkintermapview`? Pretty sure @martineau is correct.

Comment: You are mistaken. [TkinterMapView](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/TkinterMapView) was written by Tom Schimansky. It is not part of the `tkinter` module.

Comment: This question belongs [here](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/TkinterMapView/issues)

Comment: Your code works fine in my Python 3.8.13 (Windows 7) with `tkintermapview` 1.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by upgrading the tkintermapview to last version.

@acw1668 Thank you so much for help.